# iOS: display firebase data in tableView

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, tableview

I try to display data from a Firebase database into my tableView. The code worked using "Tabs View Controller", but for the purpose of the project I had to include a TableView in a classic ViewController.

Here is the code that should get the data from the database, and further include it in the tableview.

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class NewsfeedViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    var ref:DatabaseReference!,
        posts = [eventStruct]()

    @IBOutlet weak var tableview: UITableView!

    struct eventStruct {
        let title: String!
        let date: String!
        let location: String!
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        loadNews()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    func loadNews() {
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        ref.child("events").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

            if let valueDictionary = snapshot.value as? [AnyHashable:String]
            {
                let title = valueDictionary["Title"]
                let location = valueDictionary["Location"]
                let date = valueDictionary["Date"]
                self.posts.insert(eventStruct(title: title, date: date, location: location), at: 0)
            }
        })
        self.tableview.reloadData()
    }

    //Table View Content
    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return posts.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)

        let label1 = cell.viewWithTag(1) as! UILabel
        label1.text = posts[indexPath.row].title

        let label2 = cell.viewWithTag(2) as! UILabel
        label2.text = posts[indexPath.row].location

        let label3 = cell.viewWithTag(3) as! UILabel
        label3.text = posts[indexPath.row].date

        return cell
    }

}
```

I don't get any error but the data is not displayed in the tableView.

Previously I had to use override for each function that controls the tableview. If I don't have the override, I shouldn't call those functions somewhere in the code in order to have them working? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Completion block of `observe` will call async and your `self.tableview.reloadData()` will execute before that, so you need to reload the `tableView` inside the completion block after you insert the object in array.

```
func loadNews() {
    ref = Database.database().reference()
    ref.child("events").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let valueDictionary = snapshot.value as? [AnyHashable:String]
        {
            let title = valueDictionary["Title"]
            let location = valueDictionary["Location"]
            let date = valueDictionary["Date"]
            self.posts.insert(eventStruct(title: title, date: date, location: location), at: 0)
            //Reload your tableView
            self.tableview.reloadData()
        }
    })

}
```

**Note:** Also confirm once that your `delegate` and `datasource` of tableView is connected.

Comment: I've tried this solution already (this was the original version that I've wrote). This still doesn't fix the problem unfortunately.

Comment: @VictorMihaita Have you debug your code is that if block is executing, if you haven't debug the code yet try to debug it and check control is going inside that if block or not.

Comment: I just did it. The array is getting the correct data from the database and I could print each element of it. I was printing it exactly before reloading the tableView. So the problem is only with displaying the data.

Comment: @VictorMihaita If array is set than check the `delegate` and `datasource` of `tableView` is connected or not

Comment: Thank you for your help! That was the problem. I forgot to connect the delegate and the datasource. Now everything works properly.

Comment: @VictorMihaita Welcome mate :)

Comment: Done! Thanks again.