# How to add change value of table view cell label when button and add 1 to its current value

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

**So im trying to add change the number of likes label in my table view cell im just trying to add 1 to it and im not sure exactly how I can do that I already wrote code that adds 1 like when the like button is tapped in firebase I just want to show that in the table view cell is there anyway that I can just add one to the value that's already held the code I wrote

for example : I have 200 likes now the like button is tapped I want the cell label to update and show 201 likes I see the change occur in my firestore database but I want it to show
 **

```
   import UIKit
   import FBSDKLoginKit
   import Firebase
   import JGProgressHUD

 class dailyMotivationTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    //numberOfLikesGenerator()
    self.holdView.layer.cornerRadius = 19
    self.likedbuttonFIlled.isHidden = true

}

override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}


//MARK: IBOUTLETS
@IBOutlet weak var holdView: UIView!
@IBOutlet weak var likedbuttonFIlled: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var likeSavedButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var DMtextLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var DMtitleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var numberOfLikesLabel: UILabel!


//MARK: VARS/LETS
 let hud = JGProgressHUD(style: .light)



//MARK: IBACTIONS
@IBAction func likeButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {

if (Auth.auth().currentUser != nil || AccessToken.current != nil) {
        changeLikeButtonMode()
     //update like number and update like number on firebase

}
else{
    hud.textLabel.text = "Please Login to Continue!"
           hud.show(in: self.contentView)
           hud.dismiss(afterDelay: 3.0)
           hud.indicatorView = JGProgressHUDErrorIndicatorView()
    //no user login so pull up login view
    }



    //MARK: TODO when this button is tapped ALSO WANT TO STORE THIS SNAPSHOT INTO AN ARRAY THAT WE WILL SHOW IN OUR SAVED VIEW CONTROLLEr
}


func incrementLikes(){
    FirebaseReferece(.MotivationDAILY).document("540C208A-A9A0-465C-BE20-C7010D114F75").updateData(["Number of likes in daily motivation post":FieldValue.increment(Int64(1))]) { (error) in
        if error != nil {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        } else {
            print("successfully incremented data!")
        }
    }
}

func changeLikeButtonMode(){
    // so if likedbutton is tapped and the heart isnt red that means that the tag  is  = 0 so its gnna show the red heard and then also change the tag to 1 but when it is tapped again its going to change the tag to 0  and removed the red heart
            if likeSavedButton.tag == 0 //means its empty
            {
                incrementLikes()

              self.likedbuttonFIlled.isHidden = false
              likeSavedButton.tag = 1

            }

            else
            {
          self.likedbuttonFIlled.isHidden = true
              likeSavedButton.tag = 0
             self.numberOfLikesLabel.text = "\(String(-1))"
            }

}



//MARK: FUNCTIONS
func generateCellsforDailymotivation(_MotivationdataMODEL : MotivatioNDataModel) {

    DMtextLabel.text = _MotivationdataMODEL.motivationDailyScriptureModel

    DMtitleLabel.text = _MotivationdataMODEL.motivationTitleModel

    numberOfLikesLabel.text = "\(String(_MotivationdataMODEL.motivationDailyNumberOfLikes))"
}












}


import UIKit
import Firebase

//MARK: MAINVIEW MOTIVATION

    class motivationviewcontroller : UIViewController,UITableViewDataSource ,UITableViewDelegate{


var motivationThoughts = [motivationDailyModel]()
var Mous = motivationDailyModel()
var tableview : UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    print("madicc")

    print("the user logged in is \( String(describing: Auth.auth().currentUser?.email))")

    tableview =  UITableView(frame: view.bounds, style: .plain)
           tableview.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
           view.addSubview(tableview)


    var layoutGuide : UILayoutGuide!
    layoutGuide = view.safeAreaLayoutGuide

    let cellNib = UINib(nibName: "dailyMotivationTableViewCell", bundle: nil)
    tableview.register(cellNib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "DailyThoughtCELL")
    tableview.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableview.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.topAnchor).isActive = true
    tableview.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    tableview.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: layoutGuide.bottomAnchor).isActive = true


    tableview.dataSource = self
    tableview.delegate = self


    loaddailymotivation()
    self.tableview.reloadData()


}

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
  //loaddailymotivation()
    self.tableview.reloadData()

}



//======================================================================

 //MARK: LOADS THE DATA INTO THE TABLEVIEW
   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    motivationThoughts.count
   }

   func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DailyThoughtCELL", for: indexPath) as? dailyMotivationTableViewCell

        cell!.generateCellsforDailymotivation(_MotivationdataMODEL: self.motivationThoughts[indexPath.row])
        return cell!
   }



//gets the data from firebase and loads it into an array that will be called in generateCELLS
//MARK: FUNCTION THAT HANDLES GETTING THE DATA FROM FIREBASE




func loaddailymotivation() {

    FirebaseReferece(.MotivationDAILY).addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in

        if (error != nil) {
            print(error!.localizedDescription)
        } else{

            guard let snapshot = snapshot else {return}

            for allDocuments in snapshot.documents {

                let data = allDocuments.data()

                let dailyMotivationID =  data ["objectID"] as! String

                let dailymotivationTitle = data["Motivation title"] as! String //calls the data thats heald inside of motivation title in firebase

                let dailyMotivationScripture = data["daily motivation scripture"] as! String //calls the data thats heald inside of Motivation script in firebase

                let dailyMotivationNumberOfLikes = data["Number of likes in daily motivation post"]as! Int

                let MdataModel = motivationDailyModel(RealMotivationID: dailyMotivationID, RealmotivationTitle: dailymotivationTitle, RealmotivationScrip: dailyMotivationScripture, RealmotivationNumberOfLikes: dailyMotivationNumberOfLikes)

                self.motivationThoughts.append(MdataModel)
          }
        }
        self.tableview.reloadData()
     }
   }
```

Comment: Quite frankly you should not be accessing firebase from a cell class. Only view controllers or view models should do that. What you should do is have a callback into your view controller when the like button is tapped on the cell. Then the view controller should update firebase. When that's finished, then it should reload the cell's row. Keep your cells short and sweet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to just "add 1" to the value that it's being showed in the cell. However, once you update the value in Firestore, you can just read the value from the database or change your function, for it to return a value to a variable, that you will print in the screen.

For you to achieve that, I believe the best way is to read the value from Firestore and displayed, using a function to reload your page, updating the value, once it receives a new like.

```
...
getDocuments { (snapshot, error) in

if let error = error {

    print(error.localizedDescription)

} else {

    if let snapshot = snapshot {

        for document in snapshot.documents {

            let data = document.data()
            let likes = data["likes"] as? String ?? ""
            let newLikes = Likes(likes:likes)
        }
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

**This above code sample is untested, but I believe it might help you as a starting point, as how you would read and reload your page, once the value was updated.**

In case you want full examples, of how to achieve the displaying of Firestore values in cell, I would recommend you to take a look at the below posts from the Community, as well.

- [Firestore- Showing data in Tableview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50192761/firestore-showing-data-in-tableview)
- [iOS: display firebase data in tableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44499210/ios-display-firebase-data-in-tableview)
- [Display Firebase Data in UITableView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49842564/display-firebase-data-in-uitableview)

Let me know if the information helped you!